# Onmouseover data keep autorefresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a code like this below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content2").load("post_rf.php");
    // set your initial interval to kick it off
    var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 1500);
    // bind an event to mouseout of your DIV to kickstart the interval again
    $("#content2").bind("mouseout", function() {
        refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
            $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 1500);
    });
    // clear the interval on mouseover of your DIV to stop the refresh
    $("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
});
```

What I want to do is when `mouseover`, data keep autorefresh.
In this case if I drag mouse into the area of `mouseover`, it stop auto refresh until I drag `mouseout` out the area of `mouseover`.

So is it possible to set `onmouseover`, data will keep auto refresh ?

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want is the other way around,

```
    $("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {
        refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
            $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
        }, 1500);
    });
    // clear the interval on mouseover of your DIV to stop the refresh
    $("#content2").bind("mouseout", function() {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answered. This not what I want. Imagine that in the content area I have a textbox, so if I want to type into textbox surely I must quickly typing because it will refresh and clear the textbox right?

Comment: i am not sure i get you, u want the other elements in the div except the textbox to keep on refreshing??

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about your question, well the following code is responsible for making stop the auto refresh when you `mouseover`

```
$("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {
    clearInterval(refreshInterval); // it's clearing the setInterval
});
```

If you just remove/disable the the line or whole function then it won't stop the auto refresh when you move your mouse on that element.

but if you only want to occur the auti refresh only on `mouseover` and again want to stop the auto refresh on `mouseout` then you can do as follows

```
$("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {
    refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
    }, 1500);
});

$("#content2").bind("mouseout", function() {
    clearInterval(refreshInterval);
});
```

and should not use following code to start the auto refresh initially, just disable the code as follows

```
/*
var refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
    $("#content2").load('post_rf.php?randval='+ Math.random());
}, 1500);
*/
```

but you can keep the variable declarede as `var refreshInterval=0;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for answered. This not what I want. Imagine that in the content area I have a textbox, so if I want to type into textbox surely I must quickly typing because it will refresh and clear the textbox right?

Comment: Do you want to stop the auto refresh only when you want to type into the textbox and enable it again when you focus out the text box ?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, but is it possible if I type into the textobx, autorefresh keep running ?

Comment: Actually `$("#content2").bind("mouseover", function() {...})` will stop it but you can start it again when you focus in the text box.